# How to start stop azure app service plan with azure functions

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions, azure-app-service-plans

I came across the following statement in the official Microsoft Docs [Decide when to use Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/azure-compute-fundamentals/azure-functions):

> Micro-billing: Traditional computing bills for a block of time like paying a monthly or annual rate for website hosting. This method of billing is convenient but isn't always cost effective. Even if a customer's website gets only one hit a day, they still pay for a full day's worth of availability. With serverless computing, they pay only for the time their code runs. If no active function executions occur, they're not charged. For example, if the code runs once a day for two minutes, they're charged for one execution and two minutes of computing time.

To me, it sounds that it should be possoble to start and stop an Azure App Service Plan according to the request sent to the server to provision a webpage.
My question is: is it possible to do that?, and if yes, how.

The Azure function I'm thinking of, should trigger starting my App Service Plan so that the website can work on demand.

Many thanks!

Comment: This description is referring to Azure functions running under a consumption plan - app services run in a app service plan where you pay for whatever the minimum scale configuration you have setup.

Comment: Stopping all Apps on a plan won't stop the billing. However, you could consider using your Azure function to [change the pricing Tier dynamically](https://donotpanic.azurewebsites.net/2020/01/27/how-to-change-the-pricing-tier-of-my-azure-appservice-by-code/), e.g. between a Free Tier to a Paid one when load increases. There will be a delay during the switchover, and you would need to keep the app on the new plan for at least an hour before any benefit would be extracted.

Comment: Ok, but what does it happen if I scale down to a free tier with my SSL certificates and custom domain? do they go lost, or do they stay "attached" to my websites when scaling up again to a paid tier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to stop/start/pause an App Service Plan. Billing occurs for the time it exists according to the configured tier. Starting or stopping a contained app instance does not affect billing.

If you want to avoid paying for an App Service Plan, you can look into other hosting models including static web apps or hosting within Azure Functions.